# Any idea why cloneDeep is broken in apollo-utilities with vue, nginx and aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, nginx, vue.js, apollo-client

Someone has an idea why a project compiled for production, runs well in local, when I deploy it in aws with the same environment, almost all the queries to graphql throw the error:

```
TypeError: property descriptors must not specify a value or be writable when a getter or setter has been specified
```

[image]

**Local OS:**
nginx 1.14
manjaro 18

**Remote OS (AWS):**
nginx 1.14
Ubuntu 18.04

**Package.json dependencies, both enviroments:**

"@mdi/font": "^2.5.94",
"apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.2.5",
"apollo-client": "^2.4.3",
"apollo-link-context": "^1.0.8",
"apollo-link-http": "^1.5.4",
"apollo-server": "^2.1.0",
"apollo-upload-client": "^9.0.0",
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"buefy": "^0.6.7",
"cors": "^2.8.4",
"express": "^4.16.3",
"graphql": "^0.12.3",
"graphql-tag": "^2.6.1",
"moment": "^2.22.2",
"nprogress": "^0.2.0",
"sendmail": "^1.4.1",
"serve-static": "^1.13.2",
"vue": "^2.5.2",
"vue-apollo": "^3.0.0-alpha.3",
"vue-axios": "^2.1.3",
"vue-clipboard2": "^0.2.1",
"vue-router": "^3.0.1",
"vuelidate": "^0.7.4",
"vuex": "^3.0.1"

Comment: There were issues with `apollo-utilities` dependencies version. Try updating all relevant libraries to @latest versions. Strating from `vue-apollo` and all `apollo-*` libraries of your project.

Comment: @aBiscuit Check the versions and only apollo-cache-inmemory was outdated according to npm outdated. The strange thing is because in my local production environment it works and in the remote not at all.